# LinkedIn Share does not handle "#" in the URL

Tags: linkedin-api, sharethis

I am running into an issue while using Share feature of LinkedIn when the shared URL has "#" in it.

My URL looks like this: http://shoshin.glgqa07.com/#!/content/detail/High-pay-without-advanced-degrees

When I share this URL on LinkedIn, it strips out everything after "#". So the page linked on the LinkedIn is pointing to http://shoshin.glgqa07.com/.

I am using following URL to Share page to LinkedIn.
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshoshin.glgqa07.com%2F%23!%2Fcontent%2Fdetail%2FHigh-pay-without-advanced-degrees&title=The+Shoshin+Project+%3A+QA+tesing&summary=&source=

When I do View Source on the above page (Shared news on LinkedIn page), the Hidden Input field "contentUrl-shareForm" has value "http://shoshin.glgqa07.com/" instead of the complete URL.

I am using ShareThis library to implement this feature.

Does anyone know solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace the sharp sign (#) with the ASCII code %23

Comment: Yes. It is already put in as %23 in the "url=" query string parameter. See the link above.

Comment: However it sounds like an escaping problem. The # in url is used to specify the anchor.